# GlobIterator RegEx

Tags: php, regex, laravel, glob, php-7.2

I have a string with a wildcard at the end, but I don't know how many characters that string will be. How can I use GlobIterator and RegexIterator to match similar file names? The second match returns all the files from a directory, but I don't want that. I need a proper regular expression. I don't want to match the last set before the extension (ex. the files sized 250M, 500M, etc.)

```
$iterator = new GlobIterator($this->srcDir . $identifier . ".*");
```

**MATCH ON**

```
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.*
```

This returns the correct files.

```
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.250m.jpg
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.500m.jpg
```

**MATCH ON**

```
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.*
```

Returns the files:

```
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.250m.jpg
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.500m.jpg
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.250m.jpg
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.500m.jpg
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.*

```
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.250m.jpg
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.500m.jpg
```

/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.*

```
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.250m.jpg
/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.500m.jpg
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: _file names that are very similar_ Exactly what does `very simialir` mean to you please, as the concept of similiar can be very personal

Comment: Have you double check `$this->srcDir . $identifier` before output? Try with hard coded value of `/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.*` to see result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it inside a [`RegexIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexiterator.construct.php):

```
// Notice that there is no expansion pattern used here
$path = '/var/www/import/2014047-0216/YukonGold.A2014047.1620.';
$re = '~\Q' . $path . '\E(?:[^.]+\.)?\w+$~';
$regexIterator = new RegexIterator(new GlobIterator("{$path}*"), $re);
foreach ($regexIterator as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Never seen that `\Q\E` before. Looks useful, especially in character classes.

Comment: Yes. `\Q` starts to Quote and `\E` metacharacter Ends it.

Comment: This worked perfectly except for one .712 file came through... YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.txt. Can you explain the RegEx? Thank you!

Comment: @KarlHill If you expect this `1620.500m.jpg` as an expected ending so what makes `1620.721.txt` unexpected? I mean what are the rules here? The regex allows something between two dots then an extension. So anything that matches `1620.ANYTHING-BUT-PERIODS.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` is accepted at the end.

Comment: It seems to do the right thing with the rest of the files for some strange reason. It's hard to explain but on each file there is a [NAME].[IDENTIFIER].[VAR1].  and then at the very end of file path/string there can be [SIZE].[EXTENSION]. However on occasion there is [VAR2]. In between [VAR1] and [SIZE]. For this case you may have YukonGold.A2014047.1620.500m.jpg and also YukonGold.A2014047.1620.721.500m.jpg and then also YukonGold.A2014047.1620.txt and YukonGold.A2014047.1620.712.txt. These need to go in separate folders, essentially.

Comment: @KarlHill You need to make clear what are `VARX`es exactly and what rules do they follow that make them to be a `VAR`.

Comment: The VARs will always be digits.

Comment: @karlhill Then change your regex to `$re = '~\Q' . $path . '\E(?!\d+\.)(?:[^.]+\.)?\w+$~';`